# Getting correct camera information about Android device

Tags: camera, tech-specs

I was using the [Droid Hardware Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inkwired.droidinfo&hl=en&gl=US) app for Android and I checked the "camera" tab, and surprisingly for my Redmi Note 10 Pro, it only showed a **12MP**. According to the specs, Redmi Note 10 Pro should have a **108MP** camera.

Is this app giving me the wrong information or did the camera manufacturer put 12 instead of 108 or something? Could someone tell me what's happening?

EDIT: I am wondering if 108MP is the actual physical resolution of the camera?

Comment: I don't know your device but usually phones with such a sensor chip don't make 108 Mpixel pictures, that does not make sense. Instead they combine multiple pixels for decreasing image noise and they only use a certain region of the chip sensor. The hardware info apps only see the spec that Android exposes to the apps.

Comment: The device has an array of several cameras. Did the app show only one camera's specs?

Comment: @YisroelTech , it shows 2, which I believe should be for the front and the back, while the rear camera is a quad cam, should've shown 5

Comment: Try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.andr7e.deviceinfohw which seems (based on some screenshots) to have more detailed info.

Comment: @YisroelTech , this does show 108MP, but I wonder what's the difference between the two readings

Comment: Post (screenshot) the full results of both of them so we can try to compare. It's either they only read one of the 4 sensors, or (as @Robert mentioned, that it read the actual MP the result is in, since the 108 MP might be used to make the photo better but not all pixels are actually in the output.

Comment: Try to use this camera2 probe https://www.celsoazevedo.com/files/android/google-camera/dev-bsg/camera2test/